# Knockout- How to check if item in the loop exist while binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I've below HTML where I bind my array with a foreach data binding.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>index</th>
    <th>fajr</th>
    <th>zuhr</th>
    <th>asr</th>
    <th>maghrib</th>
    <th>isha</th>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: prayerData">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: index"></td>  <!-- Display the current row -->
        <td data-bind="text: fajr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: zuhr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: asr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: maghrib"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: isha"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I prepare my view model to bind to above HTML-

```
var dataFromServer = {
"1": {
    "asr": "15:50",
    "fajr": "03:00",
    "isha": "21:31",
    "maghrib": "19:02",
    "zuhr": "12:21"
},
"2": {
    "asr": "15:51",
    "fajr": "02:55",
    "isha": "21:35",
    "maghrib": "19:04",
    "zuhr": "12:21"
},
"3": {
    "asr": "15:53",
    "fajr": "02:51",
    "isha": "21:39",
    "maghrib": "19:07",
    "zuhr": "12:21"
},
"4": {
    "asr": "15:54",
    "fajr": "02:46",
    "isha": "21:42",
    "maghrib": "19:09",
    "zuhr": "12:20"
}
};



var ViewModel = function(data) {

//map data to an array
var mappedToArray = [];
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    mappedToArray.push(item);
    item.index = index;
});

this.prayerData = ko.observableArray(mappedToArray);          
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(dataFromServer));
```

Before binding of any item in foreach binding, first I want to check whether that item in array exist of not. Something like below-

For example if dataFromServer[0] would look like something like below where it is missing "asr" and "fajr" then while binding it would give error.

```
"1": {    
"isha": "21:31",
"maghrib": "19:02",
"zuhr": "12:21"
```

},

Jsfiddle for the same is

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/utdAm/

Comment: just try appending `$data` sample here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/utdAm/207/ . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of your items does not have all the properties you can use the `$data` property inside `foreach` to safely access them.

In this case if the property is missing the binding will still work it just won't display anything:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: prayerData">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: index"></td>  <!-- Display the current row -->
        <td data-bind="text: $data.fajr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.zuhr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.asr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.maghrib"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.isha"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjtL2oqb/).

You can even provide default values in the binding if the property missing with:

```
<td data-bind="text: $data.fajr || 'no fajr property'"></td>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1td61z5/)